# Binding ListBox's ItemSource in XAML doesn't work

Tags: windows, data-binding, mvvm, windows-phone-7, itemssource

I have a sample windows phone 7 project where I test some MVVM stuff, however I came across a problem.

My code looks like this:

*This is from my View which is a MainPage:*

```
  <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding _reviews}"/>
    </Grid>
```

*This is code behind for the View:*

```
      public MainPage()
        {
            this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
            // Line below makes list show what it is supposed to show
            // list.ItemsSource = (DataContext as MainPageVM)._reviews;
            DataContext = new MainPageVM();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // DataContext is set to the right object!
            var obj = list.DataContext;
        }
```

*Code for ViewModel*

```
class MainPageVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<Review> _reviews { get; set; }

    public MainPageVM()
    {
        _reviews = GetReviews();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Review> GetReviews()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Review> reviews = new ObservableCollection<Review>();
        reviews.Add(new Review() { User = "Lol", Text = "Cool", Country = "UK"});
        reviews.Add(new Review() { User = "misterX", Text = "aWESCOM APP", Country = "USA"});
        reviews.Add(new Review() { User = "meYou", Text = "The best", Country = "UK"});

        return reviews;
    }
```

*And here is my model:*

```
class Review
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Could you please point out where is the error and why I am able to set the ItemSource in code behind, but not via binding in XAML

Comment: The only thing I had to add was `public` to `class Review`. Other than that, the ItemsSource binding works fine. Are you able to reproduce this problem if you create a new project with the code you posted here?

Comment: I have created the new project with exactly the same code as I have posted (made Review class public), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, I uploaded my sample project. Do you get the same problem if you try this one? http://www.mediafire.com/?4r4n4lazau242mm

Comment: Absolutely the same apart from one keyword! I have missed public declaration of the ViewModel class. Setting it public solves the problem. Do you know why you have to have ViewModel public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your view model class does not implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and you are not raising the `PropertyChanged` event, so the view does not know that the property you are binding to has changed.

If you're not sure about how to implement this interface, take a look at [this post on Silverlight Show](http://www.silverlightshow.net/tips/How-to-implement-INotifyPropertyChanged-interface.aspx).

UPDATE: For most properties the above is true, however, in this instance because it's an `ObservableCollection` it's not necessary. However, because your view model class isn't public the view can't bind to it. Do you see any binding errors in the Output window whilst debugging?

Comment: I am not binding to the specific property of the my model, hence it doesn't need to implement INotifyPropertyChnaged and ObservableCollection has a notification mechanism. Or am I missing your point?

Comment: `_reviews` is the property you are binding to. Actually, because it's an `ObservableCollection`, you don't need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for that property, but you do need to make the view model class public so that the view can bind to it.

Comment: Yea, I have just figured it out. Do you know what is the reason for making it public, because as far as I know class by default is internal and can be accessed by other classes within the same assembly. Is it something to do with WPF Dependency property system?